# One buffer in merge sort using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, mergesort

I wrote a merge sort on iterators, but every time I create a new vector in recursion. I need to overload the `MergeSort` function, in which I will create one vector and I will use it in recursive calls.

```
template<typename Compare>
void Merge(TeamIterator begin, TeamIterator middle, TeamIterator end,
           Compare &compare, Players &current_vector) {
    TeamIterator left = begin;
    TeamIterator left_bound = middle;
    TeamIterator right = middle;
    TeamIterator right_bound = end;
    size_t current_vector_index = 0;

    while (left != left_bound && right != right_bound) {
        if (compare(*right, *left)) {
            current_vector[current_vector_index] = *right;
            current_vector_index = current_vector_index + 1;
            right = right + 1;
        } else {
            current_vector[current_vector_index] = *left;
            current_vector_index = current_vector_index + 1;
            left = left + 1;
        }
    }
    std::copy(left, left_bound, &current_vector[current_vector_index]);
    std::copy(right, right_bound, &current_vector[current_vector_index]);
    std::copy(current_vector.begin(), current_vector.end(), begin);
}

template<typename Compare>
void MergeSort(TeamIterator begin, TeamIterator end, Compare &compare) {
    auto size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size < 2) {
        return;
    }

    TeamIterator middle = std::next(begin, size / 2);
    MergeSort(begin, middle, compare);
    MergeSort(middle, end, compare);
    Players current_vector(size);
    Merge(begin, middle, end, compare, current_vector);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "overload" here? Can you annotate your code snippet with a comment showing which part you have a question about? I can't understand your question as written.

Comment: @jtbandes I concur this needs clarification. I *think* the OP is trying to get the local `Players`, in `MergeSort` *out* of being local, and instead have a single vector.. somewhere... that is used during the entire recursive descent, much like `begin` and `end` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to grasp that, baring the complicated workings of some [in-place merge implementation](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f04/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf), a traditional merge-sort requires additional `N` space for `N` items.You're implementation utilizes that idea, but splits it across a plethora of vectors, each at any given level of the recursive descent. Your question is, as I read it, how you can stop that and instead use a *single* vector for all temp storage.

I'm not going to validate whether or not your `Merge` or `MergeSort` algorithms even work. Rather, I'll tell you how you can setup what you seek by providing an *intermediate* function that provides the `N` space, then propagate that down to a inner `MergeSort` that expects *three* iterators; not two. The third is the target location for temporary storage of the merge being done at the current descent

First the main front-end, which appears the same as yours in regards to arguments.

```
template<typename Compare>
void MergeSort(TeamIterator begin, TeamIterator end, Compare &compare) 
{
    auto size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size < 2) {
        return;

   Player tmp(size); // the one-time temp-space allocation of N items.
   MergeSort(begin, end, tmp.begin(), compare);
}
```

Notice this is calling a `MergeSort` overload that takes *three* iterators; not two.  That would be implemented as:

```
template<typename Compare>
void MergeSort(TeamIterator begin, TeamIterator end, TeamIterator tmp, Compare &compare) 
{
    auto size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size < 2) {
        return;

    TeamIterator middle = std::next(begin, size / 2);
    MergeSort(begin, middle, tmp, compare);
    MergeSort(middle, end, std::next(tmp, size / 2), compare);
    Merge(begin, middle, end, tmp, compare);
}
```

And finally, *that* is calling a `Merge` that takes *four* iterators, not three::

```
template<typename Compare>
void Merge(TeamIterator begin, TeamIterator middle, TeamIterator end,
           TeamIterator tmp, Compare &compare) {

    TeamIterator left = begin;
    TeamIterator right = middle;
    TeamIterator dst = tmp;

    while (left != middle && right != end) 
    {
        if (compare(*right, *left))
            *dst++ = *right++;
        else
            *dst++ = *left++;
    }

    // account for early termination from right-side finish.
    if (left != middle)
    {
        std::copy(left, middle, dst);
        std::advance(dst, std::distance(left, middle));
    }

    // copy move everything we sorted back into the partition
    std::copy(tmp, dst, begin);
}
```

From there, your caller will do just what it's doing now: invoke `MergeSort(begin, end, compare)`. That sets up the one temporary space allocation that is then pushed through all the recursive calls.

Apologies for any typos, but hopefully you get the idea.